# Get data from 2 states in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, interpreter, monad-transformers

I'm writing a small interpreter in Haskell that uses the StateT-monad (in combination with IO) and the EitherT monad. Now I want to apply an integer function to the values interpreted by the interpArithmic function. But the problem is that the interpArithmic itself also has the `EitherT InterpError (StateT Environment IO ())` signature. How can I extract the values interpreted by the interpArithmic function, use it in my bAritHelper function, add them together (for example) and return there new value?

```
bArithHelper :: Arithmic -> Arithmic -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> EitherT InterpError (StateT Environment IO Value)
bArithHelper a b func = 
-- Body of this function is completely broken, don't know how to fix this.
do
    st1 <- interpArithmic a
    st2 <- interpArithmic b
    return $ do  
        env1 <- get st1
        env2 <- get st2
        return Num
    liftM $ 

-- This function interpretes an arithmic expression and returns it's result.
-- An error message (int the form of Error) is returned in case something goes wrong.
interpArithmic :: Arithmic -> Either InterpError (StateT Environment IO Value)
interpArithmic (ConstInteger a) = return (Num a)
interpArithmic (BinaryArithmicExpression Add a b) = bArithHelper a b (\x -> \y -> x + y)
```

Or is there some other way to handle errors and use the StateT monad in combination with IO?

PS: I would like to retain EitherT as the outer monad transformer, because that way I don't have to use some sort of case in do-block.

Comment: Can you add the definitions of the data types Arithmic & Value? Also InterpError and Environment are missing but that's less important since you're not using them in the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit of context missing from your code so I've done my best to piece it together into something that compiles by itself. Your type signatures also have parentheses that extend a bit too far out. Presumably `Either` was meant to be `EitherT` as well.

I'm still slightly confused by what exactly you want since it seems like you're almost there, but is the following akin to what you're looking for (this compiles as you would expect)? Perhaps you think that `st1 <- interpArithmic` is only "unwrapping one layer" and therefore gives back a `StateT ...` when in fact `st1` is a `Value`?

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

type EitherT = ExceptT

data Arithmic = ConstInteger Integer | BinaryArithmicExpression Exp Arithmic Arithmic

data Value = Num Integer

data Exp = Add

type InterpError = String

type Environment = String

getVal :: Value -> Integer
getVal (Num x) = x

bArithHelper :: Arithmic -> Arithmic -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> EitherT InterpError (StateT Environment IO) Value
bArithHelper a b func =
    do
        st1 <- interpArithmic a
        st2 <- interpArithmic b
        return $ Num (func (getVal st1) (getVal st2))

interpArithmic :: Arithmic -> EitherT InterpError (StateT Environment IO) Value
interpArithmic (ConstInteger a) = return (Num a)
interpArithmic (BinaryArithmicExpression Add a b) = bArithHelper a b (\x -> \y -> x + y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing some data type definitions, so I inferred from the context what I thought you meant. Here's what I got:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.Trans.Either
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

data InterpError = InterpError () deriving (Show)
data Environment = Environment () deriving (Show)
data Op = Add deriving (Show)
data Value = Num Integer deriving (Show)

data Arithmic = ConstInteger Integer
                | BinaryArithmicExpression Op Arithmic Arithmic
                deriving (Show)

bArithHelper :: Arithmic -> Arithmic -> (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> EitherT InterpError (StateT Environment IO) Value
bArithHelper a b func = do
    Num st1 <- interpArithmic a
    Num st2 <- interpArithmic b
    return $ Num $ func st1 st2

-- This function interpretes an arithmic expression and returns it's result.
-- An error message (int the form of Error) is returned in case something goes wrong.
interpArithmic :: Arithmic -> EitherT InterpError (StateT Environment IO) Value
interpArithmic (ConstInteger a) = return (Num a)
interpArithmic (BinaryArithmicExpression Add a b) = bArithHelper a b (\x -> \y -> x + y)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    res <- runStateT (runEitherT $ interpArithmic (BinaryArithmicExpression Add (ConstInteger 2) (ConstInteger 3))) $ Environment ()
    print res
```